# Avoiding bad self-intersections

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, intersection-theory

Let $M^n$ and $\overline{M}^{n+1}$ be smooth manifolds, with $M$ compact. Suppose $M$ can be immersed in $\overline{M}$. Is it true that $M$ can be immersed in $\overline{M}$ in such a way that it always intersects itself transversely?

Comment: Yes, though I don't have a reference for you.

Comment: I strongly believe this is true, but I don't know a proof for it..

Comment: @Mike:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448843/reference-for-self-intersections-of-immersions is related, but definitely not the same thing.    There, you recommend Hirsch.  I don't have a copy - could this result be there?

Comment: Yes, try Hirsch exercise 1 p83.