# remove self-intersections of a closed curve in a compact 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Assume I have a closed curve $\gamma:\mathbb{S}^1\mapsto M$ of a compact $3$-manifold $M$. I want to remove the self-intersections, by looking at a ball (which is convex) in one of the maps, which contains self-intersections. In this ball I want to replace all the curves, by replacing the "pieces that map into this ball" with straight paths, like this:

[image]

And these straights are then easy to rid of self-intersections.
I have a problem with the choice of the ball though. I feel like running into a problem, if I have countably many "pieces that map into the ball". First of, is this even a problem? or is it no problem to replace countably many things in the curve? And if it is, can I somehow choose the ball differently, so that I only have finitely many of those straights? And if it isnt possible, is it, if I add, that the manifold has to be differentiable? or smooth?

Comment: I suggest you look at the Hahn-Marurkiewicz theorem.  A corollary is path connected Hausdorff spaces are arc connected.  There you' ll discover how a curve can be smooth out so it does not cross itself.  It is not a simple proof.  General Topology by Stephen Willard has a proof.

Comment: See Mike Miller's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448843/reference-for-self-intersections-of-immersions?rq=1